# Cannot deserialize a class only when sent by the server-to-client, works vice versa

Tags: java, deserialization, utf

The streams used to work, but suddenly just stopped two days ago,  and I can't get it fixed.

The client creates and successfully sends a User object and a Message object (serialize by the client and deserialize by the server). When the clients receives any of the two classes (serialized by the server and deserialized by the client), I get exceptions, mainly:

```
java.io.UTFDataFormatException
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTFSpan(ObjectInputStream.java:3704)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTFBody(ObjectInputStream.java:3658)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:3458)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:1239)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.readNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:804)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDescriptor(ObjectInputStream.java:988)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:2032)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1907)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2209)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1742)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:514)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:472)
    at Model.MessageClient$1.run(MessageClient.java:69)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Every so often, I get:

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: Model.Message; class invalid for deserialization
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass$ExceptionInfo.newInvalidClassException(ObjectStreamClass.java:174)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.checkDeserialize(ObjectStreamClass.java:921)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2210)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1742)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:514)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:472)
```

#### Client side - streams

```
public MessageClient(String ip, int port, String usernameStr, ImageIcon icon, Controller controller) {
    this.user = new User(usernameStr, icon);
    this.controller = controller;
    this.port = port;
    this.ip = ip;
    this.messageBuffer = new Buffer<>();
    this.contacts = new ArrayList<>(); //(ArrayList<Model.User>) readObjectFromFile("files/contacts");
    setUpStreams();
    setUpThreads();
}

public void setUpStreams(){
    try {
        s = new Socket(ip, port);
        try {
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            oos.writeObject(user);
            oos.flush();
            users = new ArrayList<>();
            setUpThreads();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void setUpThreads(){
    t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                try {
                    Object o = ois.readObject();
                    if (o.getClass().isAssignableFrom(Message.class)) {
                        receiveMessage((Message) o);
                    }
                    if (o.getClass().isAssignableFrom(ArrayList.class)) {
                        updateUsers((ArrayList<Model.User>) o);
                    }
                } catch(EOFException e){
                    System.out.println("stopped");
                    t2.stop();
                    t1.stop();
                } catch(IOException | ClassNotFoundException e){
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                try {
                    Message currMessage = messageBuffer.get();
                    oos.writeObject(currMessage);
                    oos.flush();
                } catch(IOException | InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    });
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
}
```

#### Server-side streams

```
@Override
public synchronized void run() {

    while (socket.isConnected() && !socket.isClosed()) {
            try {
                Object o = ois.readObject();
                ih.addToBuffer((Model.Message) o);
            } catch (EOFException e) {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                    t2.stop();
                    t1.stop();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

    }
    chm.put(user, null);
    clients.remove(this);
    sendAll(new Message(user.getUsername() + " has disconnected", null));

}

private class InputHandler implements Runnable{
    private Buffer<Model.Message> inputBuffer;

    public InputHandler(){
        inputBuffer = new Buffer<>();
    }

    public void addToBuffer(Message msg){
        inputBuffer.put(msg);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
        Object o = null;
        while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
            Message temp = null;
            Message sendable = null;
            try {
                temp = inputBuffer.get();
                sendable = new Message(temp.getText(), temp.getIcon(), temp.getRecipients(), temp.getSender());
                sendable.setCurrID();
                sendable.setUploaded(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                sendSelect(sendable ,sendable.getSender());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
public void sendSelect(Message msg, User selectedUser){
        Client currClient;
        if(!chm.containsKey(selectedUser)) {
            try {
                oos.writeObject(new Message(selectedUser.getUsername() + "not found", null));
                oos.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if ((currClient = chm.get(selectedUser)) != null) {
            try {
                currClient.oos.writeObject((Model.Message) msg);
                currClient.oos.flush();
                msg.setDownloaded(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                callback.downloadTimestamp(msg);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            addUnsent(selectedUser, msg);
        }
}
```

The classes I serialized copy and pasted.

The classpath is the same, all fields are serializable and the have no-arg constructors. I also made sure both encoding on are set to UTF-8

#### Message

```
package Model;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Message implements Serializable{
    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3930131856060689940L;

    private static int nextID = 0;
    private int currID;

    private final String text;
    private final ImageIcon icon;

    private Timestamp uploaded;
    private Timestamp downloaded;

    private final User sender;
    private final LinkedList<User> recipients;

    public Message(){
        currID = nextID;
        nextID++;
        this.text = null;
        this.icon = null;
        sender = null;
        recipients = null;
    }
    public Message(String text, User sender){
        currID = nextID;
        nextID++;
        this.text = text;
        this.icon = null;
        this.sender = sender;
        this.recipients = null;

    }
    public Message(String text, ImageIcon icon, User sender) {
        currID = nextID;
        nextID++;
        this.text = text;
        this.icon = icon;
        this.sender = sender;
        this.recipients = null;

    }
    public Message(String text, ImageIcon icon, LinkedList<User> recipients, User sender) {
        currID = nextID;
        nextID++;
        this.text = text;
        this.icon = icon;
        this.sender = sender;
        this.recipients = recipients;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj instanceof Message){
            if( ((Message) obj).getCurrID() == this.currID ){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
    public ImageIcon getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }
    public Timestamp getUploaded() {
        return uploaded;
    }
    public Timestamp getDownloaded() {
        return downloaded;
    }
    public Model.User getSender(){return sender;}
    public int getCurrID(){return currID;}
    public void setCurrID(){currID = nextID; nextID++;}
    public LinkedList<User> getRecipients(){
        return recipients;
    }
    public void setUploaded(Timestamp uploaded) {
        this.uploaded = uploaded;
    }
    public void setDownloaded(Timestamp downloaded) {
        this.downloaded = downloaded;
    }
}
```

#### User

```
package Model;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.Serial;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class User implements Serializable{
    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5886308724572898536L;

    private String username;
    private ImageIcon image;

    public User(String username, ImageIcon image){
        this.username = username;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return username.hashCode();
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj!=null && obj instanceof User)
            return username.equals(((User)obj).getUsername());
        return false;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return username;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I called setUpThread() twice, messing with the input stream. So if you get this kind of problem, make sure you don't initialize your threads (that are reading input stream from the sockets) more than once.

Comment: hoprefully someone finds it useful, thats why i'll leave this question up! I didn't find a similar answer elsewhere